# Can we change the limits for this function?

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, analysis

Let f be in $C^{1}$ and we know $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}$ f(x) exist.

Can I change the Limits this way?

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$?

We know that $f'$ is Steady and for a steady function is we are allowed to do this.  For example: $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{\frac{1}{x}}=e^{\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{x}}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What do you mean when you claim that $f'$ is “Steadly”?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I mean Steady. Like f is Steady if $\lim_{x \rightarrow \x__0}=f(x_0)$ exist. Or the Epsilon- Delta definition

Comment: Do you mean “continuous”?

Comment: Yes, this is what i meant. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

The first limit is equal $L:=\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x).$ If it does not exist there is no equality, whatever the second limit is. Otherwise we have
$${f(x+h)-f(x)\over h}=f'(\xi_{x,h})$$ where $|\xi_{x,h}-x|\le |h|.$ If $x\to \infty $ then $\xi_{x,h}\to \infty .$ We thus get $$\lim_{x\to \infty}{f(x+h)-f(x)\over h}=L$$ Therefore it does not depend on $h.$ Hence the second limit is equal $L.$

Comment: I don't think the first limit necessarily exists. You may have proved that both limits are equal if they do exist.

Comment: If the first limit does not exist there is nothing to prove.

Comment: Well, the question asks if equality always holds. If it does not exist, then it is not equal to the second limit, which is (always) $0$. But I see that you have already edited this in now.

Comment: @legionwhale Actually I thought there was a misprint in OP and the existence of the limit of $f'$ was assumed in place of $f.$

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not equal in general.

Let $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = l$. Then, note that for any $h \neq 0$,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \frac{l-l}{h} = 0$$

Therefore,

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = 0$$

for any such $f$. However, the limit on the LHS may not even exist. Consider $f$ given by:

$$f(x) = \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}, \; \; x \neq 0$$

and $f(0) = 0$. Then, $f \in C^1$ and its limit at infinity exists. However, $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ is divergent.